# Regular expression doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-chrome, validation

I am trying to add validation to an email field using JavaScript and have attempted to use the following pattern:

```
pattern="[a-z0-9]\.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z-]+(\.[a-z]{2,})+"
```

This works fine in several browsers but not Chrome, where I always get some variation of the following error:

```
Pattern attribute value [a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z-]+(.[a-z]{2,})+ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z-]+(.[a-z]{2,})+/v: Invalid character in character class
```

I've tried a lot of variations, including escaping several characters or removing them entirely, with the same results. I'm assuming this has something to do with the /v flag, but I have no idea how to fix it. Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Escape literal `-`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `{`, `}`, `/` and `|` symbols in character classes. I.e. ``pattern="[a-z0-9\].!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`\{\|\}~\-]+@[a-z\-]+(?:\.[a-z]{2,})+"``